# Personal Folder Display will not turn off, even with Terminal Command

Tags: appearance

Personal Folder cannot be turned off, either in Settings or with the Terminal command. Is this a bug in version 22.04? Have never seen this in the previous versions.

Comment: What is " Personal Folder" ? The icon to your home directory on the desktop? What terminal command did you use?